# how to do a response after calling a php file?

Tags: php, jquery

I have a jQuery function that call a PHP file via the POST method. I would like to retrieve values from the PHP file in a specific div. I do this:

```
function scarica_file (i) {
  var input = $("<input>").attr("type", "hidden").attr("name", "c1").val(i);
  $('.fmscarica').append($(input));
  $('.fmscarica').attr('action', "scarica_analisi_mercato.php").submit() 
}

function (response) {
  // alert(response);
  $("#result").html( response ).show();
  $("#result").delay(4000).fadeOut(); 
};
}
```

If I delete the `response` function all is OK, but in this way it does not work. Any suggestions? Thanks a lot

Comment: It looks like you're doing an actual form submit (in a really odd way).  Use ajax instead. There are plenty of guides/tutorials out there to get you started, in addition to the jQuery docs for [.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) and [.post](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**main.js**

```
 $('.fmscarica').on('click', function() {
      $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'functions.php',
        data: ({
          action: 'prod_dropdown',
        }),
        success: function(response) {
          $('#result').html(response);
        }
      });
    });
```

**functions.php**

```
    $action = (isset($_POST['action'])) ? $_POST['action'] : 3;
```